# Mono.framework is missing on my mac ... but it's... there?

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono

Please help me interwebs.

I'm having trouble getting my xamarin app to work. I've done a reinstall of Mac OS X and installed Xamarin using the installer, which adds mono and all the rest of it.

Now when I open up terminal and type which mono i get
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono

...which is what I expect.

But when I navigate to that place (again in terminal) there's nothing there.

From my root folder I go "cd System/Library/Frameworks " and then hit ls and I get a looooong list of installed frameworks but no Mono.framework.

If I go to Apple > About this Mac > System Report > Frameworks Mono IS listed. I can execute Mono commands on the command line. If I look in paths.d the specified path for mono is /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono but I can't find that location so how is it even a thing?

My linux skills are not great, can anyone please help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: `cd /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking in the 'wrong' Library folder. There are a few different Library folders. There is one under the Disk Drive (root) directory, one under the User directory, one under the System directory. I think they are all hidden by default. So you need to set your folder/view options explicitly to show the Library folder since it might be hidden by default. The directory you are looking for is directly under you Disk Drive (root).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in the one under System!